# Permission denied when setting wkhtmltopdf path with go-wkhtmltopdf package

Tags: html, go, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the go-wkhtmltopdf package in my Golang project and I've downloaded wkhtmltopdf to my PC. However, when I use the SetPath function to specify the path to the wkhtmltopdf binary, I receive the following error:

```
fork/exec /usr/local/bin: permission denied
```

I believe this error is related to a permissions issue on my local machine. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

I tried using a different path before `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` but when I used that I got the error `fork/exec /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: no such file or directory`. But when I check `which wkhtmltopdf`. I get the response `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: need `chmod +x path/to/wkhtmltopdf`?

Comment: i tried this but it didn't help

Comment: Note that the error message cites `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. To me, this is a hint at that some pretty silly error might be happening in the real code.

Comment: What is the value passed to `SetPath`? Please note that it should be the directory which holds wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: If you check through which, then it suggests the path /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf. But if you pass this path as a value to SetPath, then there will be an error no such file or directory. And on a similar error on Stack Overflow there was an answer that the path should not be to the wkhtmltopdf itself, but to the bin folder, and if you specify the path like this, the error will be /usr/local/bin: permission denied